# What settings can my app control to conserve battery life?

Tags: android, settings, power-management

I was wondering what settings an application can control to improve battery life in the Android environment.  On most laptops, you can control screen brightness, wireless adapter settings, etc, as a means to conserve battery life.  Are there any such controls in Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the settings provider:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

An example can be found here:

http://www.mensus.net/phone/toggle.shtml